# Angular with PrimeNg Dropdown doesn't make sense

Tags: angular, typescript

https://primeng.org/dropdown

If you click StackBlitz, you'll see this

```
<h5>Advanced with Templating, Filtering and Clear Icon</h5>
<p-dropdown
  [options]="countries"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
  optionLabel="name"
  [filter]="true"
  filterBy="name"
  [showClear]="true"
  placeholder="Select a Country"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
    <div class="country-item country-item-value" *ngIf="selectedCountry">
      <div>{{ selectedCountry.name }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">
    <div class="country-item">
      <div>{{ country.name }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

In the TS file,

```
selectedCountry: string;
countries: any[];
```

How are they able to use **selectedCountry.name**

String do not contain the properties like name, age, etc.

The error I receive is

> error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you found a solution. But it worked for me.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'dropdown-filter-demo',
templateUrl: './dropdown-filter-demo.html',})

export class DropdownFilterDemo implements OnInit {
@Input() countries: any[] = [];
@Input() selectedCountry: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.countries = [
        { name: 'Australia', code: 'AU' },
        { name: 'Brazil', code: 'BR' },
        { name: 'China', code: 'CN' },
        { name: 'Egypt', code: 'EG' },
        { name: 'France', code: 'FR' },
        { name: 'Germany', code: 'DE' },
        { name: 'India', code: 'IN' },
        { name: 'Japan', code: 'JP' },
        { name: 'Spain', code: 'ES' },
        { name: 'United States', code: 'US' },
    ];
}}
```

If don't wanna use any as type, you could made the type for accepts both (string and object that with name and code) I hope I've help